# How to find every index of a given int in an array?

Tags: java, arrays, int, max

I am trying to find every occurrence of the given index "max", in this array, and confirm that there is only one index with the given value max.

```
    for ( int i = 0; i < posNum; i++) {
        if ( possibilitynum[i] > max) {
            max = possibilitynum[i];
        }
    }

    if (Arrays.asList(possibilitynum).lastIndexOf(max) != Arrays.asList(possibilitynum).indexOf(max)) {
        String[] button = { possibilities[Arrays.asList(possibilitynum).indexOf(max)].substring(possibilities[Arrays.asList(possibilitynum).indexOf(max)].length()-(possibilities[Arrays.asList(possibilitynum).indexOf(max)].length()-36-(main.category.length()))), possibilities[Arrays.asList(possibilitynum).lastIndexOf(max)].substring(possibilities[Arrays.asList(possibilitynum).lastIndexOf(max)].length()-(possibilities[Arrays.asList(possibilitynum).lastIndexOf(max)].length()-36-(main.category.length())))};
        int choice=JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Two items have "+max+" of the keywords you entered! Which item is correct?", "NEED INPUT ASAP",
                JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE, 0, null, button, null);

    } else {
        main.theActualLink=possibilities[Arrays.asList(possibilitynum).indexOf(max)];
    }
```

Max occurs multiple times, so Arrays.asList(possibilitynum).indexOf(max) will only return the first index whereas I need all of them. Arrays.asList(possibilitynum).lastIndexOf(max) will only return the last, so I am able to find two of the indexes, but not all of them. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question, then I think the easiest solution is to add a `count` to your existing `for` loop. Something like

```
int count = 0;
for ( int i = 0; i < posNum; i++) {
    if ( possibilitynum[i] > max) {
        max = possibilitynum[i];
        count = 1;
    } else if (possibilitynum[i] == max) {
        count++;
    }
}
```

**Edit**

If you really want to store the indexes, you could add them to a `List` like

```
List<Integer> maxIndexes = new ArrayList<>();
for ( int i = 0; i < posNum; i++) {
    if ( possibilitynum[i] > max) {
        max = possibilitynum[i];
        maxIndexes.clear();
        maxIndexes.add(i);
    } else if (possibilitynum[i] == max) {
        maxIndexes.add(i);
    }
}
int count = maxIndexes.size(); // <-- for example
```

Comment: I think he's wanting the indeces of all occurances of max though. So instead of `int count` you probably want to maintain a list of indeces and clear it whenever a new max is found.

Comment: Thats exactly what I was looking to do, thank you @Elliott Frisch

Comment: @BenOrgera You're welcome and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), and if your question is answered please [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/243725).